# in NumPy, how to insert an array into another array

Tags: arrays, numpy

For example, if I have a NumPy array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.zeros(5)
```

How can I insert `b` to the beginning of `a`?

I know I can make a new array of size `len(a)+len(b)` and do slice assignment, but is there a way to directly insert the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.concatenate`:

```
>>> np.concatenate((b, a))
    array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,
        8.,  9.])
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
c = np.hstack([b, a])
```